# Zoom in Chart Control

Tags: c#, microsoft-chart-controls

Do we Zoom the ChartArea Inside ChartControl only on the Bais on X Axis , i follow [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/MSWinWebChart/thread/B5017523-111D-4710-A7A6-9131AD807C30) but only X Axis is Zoom as per Code Can we Zoom Both the Axis on the basis of X axis or we need to write the code for YAxis

Thanks 
Shashank

Answer (score 0):

You can zoom both of the chart's axis. You turn the y axis code on the same way that is indicated for the X axis in the article.  With both axis enabled, you can zoom left-right/up-down or any other combination of mouse movements.